# WCF web service and DynamoDB scaling/performance issue with SDK database object

Tags: wcf, scaling, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to creating .NET restful web services and need to grasp the best practices for performance and scaling the following.

I am conncecting to Amazon AWS DynamoDB using their .NET SDK wrapper in C#. My code creates an object that stores the credentials necessary to interface with DynamoDB. What concerns me is that this calls is instantiated on every call. The credentials are stored in my profiles.settings collection and never change.

What I am wondering is whether there is a better way to get these values and create the object once and somehow persist it. I do not know whether or not it is better for performance and scalability to create each time or to look for some type of application cache simulation/alternative that applies to WCF web services.

I also do not know whether static objects come into play here or whether I should steer clear of them.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a static object to persist your credentials considering that those credentials are stored in your config file and as you have mentioned they do not change. Related to the WCF REST aspect, you could really simply your life by using WebAPI the new REST "framework" from Microsoft. WCF is kind of clumsy when it comes to REST.

Comment: Thanks very much. I ended up going with a class that has static properties and methods. I'd investigate WebAPI and REST framework if I had the time but the WCF seems to be doing everything my architectural requirements necessitated relatively easy but had I heard of it before reading your comment I definitely would have given it a shot. Thanks very much!

Comment: If you find the answer useful please give it a vote, if not, leave it as it is :).